# how to get the servers public keys in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am working on an application in nodejs. I have created a server and i have some other servers. when the main server asks the other servers  should reply with their IP address and their public keys. I am considering to use seaport https://github.com/substack/seaport/blob/master/readme.markdown but the things are not working.

```
[lilac@ LILAC revanth] $ seaport listen 9090
bash: seaport: command not found[lilac@ LILAC revanth] $ cat server.js
var seaport = require('seaport');
var ports = seaport.connect('localhost', 9090);
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.end('beep boop\r\n');
 });

server.listen(ports.register('web@1.2.3'));
[lilac@ LILAC revanth] $ cat client.js
 var seaport = require('seaport');
 var ports = seaport.connect(9090);
 var request = require('request');

  ports.get('web@1.2.x', function(ps) {
    var u = 'http://' + ps[0].host + ':' + ps[0].port;
    request(u).pipe(process.stdout);
   });
```

This is the error i am getting

Comment: Why it's not working?

Comment: When i use the seaport listen 9090 command it is givving the error and when i run the node server.js then it is taking so long and there is no output.

Comment: You must specify in question which error

Comment: you need `sudo npm install -g seaport`

Comment: That worked. But the server.js is not providing any output. Also how should i configure the seaport so that when a client asks then the server it should reply with the avaliable public keys + Ip addresses.

Comment: hey could you explain me what is web@1.2.3. I want to replace it with my port number